# WPF: Tab GroupBox item appears and disappears after cleaning & building

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, visual-studio-2012

Using VS2012 and .NET 4.0, I have the following block of code in a UserControl:

```
    <GroupBox Name="LocalGroup">

        <GroupBox.Header>
            <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" 
                       Text="Local Rules">

            </TextBlock>
        </GroupBox.Header>

        <StackPanel Margin="20,8,10,0"
                    Orientation="Vertical" >

        <local:LocalRulesHeader />

        </StackPanel>
    </GroupBox>
```

When I build the program the line '' gets the blue squiggly underline with the error message of

```
    Error   16  The component 'ToolLibrary.LocalRulesHeader' does not have a resource 
identified by the URI '/ToolLibrary;component/xamlclasses/localrulesheader.xaml'.
```

Yet when I clean the project the blue squiggly line disappears and the LocalRulesHeader is displayed in the GroupBox as expected.  I do a build and the blue squiggly line and error message reappear.

I have tried cleaning the project as well as shutting down VS and restarting to no avail.

Has anyone experienced this and found a way to resolve?

Comment: Is your code stored on a network drive? That can cause weird issues like this.

Comment: @Sheridan No, the code is all stored locally on my hard drive.